# Change drawable.xml item colors programmatically

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I'am using this tab1.xml drawable as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/activated" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/activated" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

So, how to access this tab1.xml drawable and change the **normal** image color programmatically?

Comment: It's an image, you basically need to work on the bitmap of that image.

Comment: Could you please show me how to achieve this? How to get access to tab1.xml drawable and modify the drawables inside?

Comment: Could you give me an answer who DOWNVOTED my question? Wiseman

Comment: `Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.normal ); 
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
myIcon.setColorFilter(filter);` Try this

Comment: Btw, why do you want to do that? Makes no sense to me. It's already used in a selector.

Comment: I tried your solution but with no luck. I want to use this because I don't want to use more image resources in my app, just I want to apply a color filter to them according to the applied theme.

Comment: The code I posted works just fine. To show this image, you just put it as the background of your view like this: `view.setBackground(myIcon);` IDK which view it is, it can be ImageView/Button

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to apply a `ColorFilter`.

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal);
Color newColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.new_color);
d.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: It's not the exact same code. Anyway probably the selector keeps referring to the original `@drawable` resource. In this case you can try to get rid of the selector and manage your states programmatically with listeners. Like - when your  button is clicked, change its background from `normal` to `activated`, and viceversa.

Comment: @m iav that's what I did actually. Thank you